# Postgresql slow query with limit and order by

Tags: postgresql

I'm having trouble with a select query, it's a simple query to select the most recent row from a table, but the query planner is doing something weird.

```
SELECT id FROM plots WHERE fk_id='73a711a5-cb31-545d-b8d6-75c2a0e3ba9d' 
  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1


Limit  (cost=0.43..155.97 rows=1 width=24)
  ->  Index Scan Backward using idx_plot_created_at on plots  
      (cost=0.43..304694.48 rows=1959 width=24)
        Filter: (fk_id = '73a711a5-cb31-545d-b8d6-75c2a0e3ba9d'::uuid)
```

And it takes about 2,8 seconds to execute. But when I remove the order by and limit, then it uses the index on the fk_id field and returns 6 results in 102 ms. Shouldn't Postgresql just read the 6 results using the fk_id index and order them by the created_at field? Instead it seems to scan the table using the index on the field that is used for the ORDER BY clause and will then check every row with the Filter condition. Why does it do that?

Comment: A combined index on (fk_id, created_at) will probably work best.

Comment: If you want to force it to use that index, and without changing anything in your schema, you could do something like `SELECT id FROM (SELECT id, created_at FROM plots WHERE fk_id = 'xxxxx') ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: Creating an index on fk_id, created_at worked. The second query using a subquery and select produces the same query plan.

I guess I'll close the question now, or Eelke can post an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: @TõnisM Whoops looks like postgres optimised the subquery away. Have a look at this if you want, it describes your issue and 
why my subquery didn't change the plan (and how to make it actually do so): https://www.endpoint.com/blog/2009/04/07/offset-0-ftw

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with query planner. it is all about the table statistics, pg query planner thinks, due to the tbale stats, that doing a search on created at index will result much faster compared to fk_id. when you remove order by, query planner is comparing b/w old sequential scan v/s index scan on where clause.